# Problem Reading Embedded Resource With ASP.NET Core 3.1 in Console App

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm failing at being able to read embedded resources in ASP.NET Core 3.1. Specifically, I'm following the example in the docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I've updated my csproj file to the following adding the `<GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Data\sessions.json" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Data\speakers.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\EFLib\EFLib.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RepositoryLib\RepositoryLib.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SeedDataLib\SeedDataLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have console app as follows and I get the error below when I run it.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var manifestEmbeddedProvider =
            new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Program).Assembly); // ERROR HERE
```

{"Could not load the embedded file manifest 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.xml' for assembly 'TestConsoleApp'."}

I'm basically trying to do what I use to do in ASP.NET Core 2 which was this and it's not working.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames(); // debugging purposes only to get list of embedded resources
```

Comment: 1.`new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Program).Assembly);` used in Startup.cs not console app.2.`assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();` could work well in asp.net core3.1,what is your scenario?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue you described. Make sure that you added the following package reference to the `.csproj` where embedded resources are declared. Once I added it to my project and rebuilt the solution, it started working.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="3.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```